# In CSS, is there a way to format floating point numbers to a specific number of digits to the right of the decimal point?

Tags: css, floating-point, formatting, precision, usability

I am trying to determine if, using just CSS, there is there a way to format floating point numbers to a specific number of digits to the right of the decimal point?

The reason I want to do this is that I need to use a website that displays a ***massive amount of continually updating data*** in tables.  (Because the data is continually updating, I can't just export the data into a spreadsheet.)

The values are floating point and range from 0 to 9999.  The number of fractional digits varies from 0 to 7.  For the most part, I have no use for anything beyond hundredths (2 places to the right of the decimal point).  The exception is for values ranging from 0 to 9, but I'm willing to forego that case, if necessary.

This is an tiny example of how the data is currently displayed:

```
   9484.83
 133.57643
 1344.5432
 9.5848274
  58.48381
    5989.1
 1.5847493
     1.348
```

As you can see, it's hard to read the data with that presentation.  Ideally, I would like to use a CSS overlay to reformat that data as:

```
   9484.83
    133.57
   1344.54
     9.584
     58.48
   5989.10
     1.584
     1.348
```

If that's not possible, I'm fine with:

```
   9484.83
    133.57
   1344.54
      9.58
     58.48
   5989.10
      1.58
      1.34
```

Using CSS, I can easily enforce a maximum width for the HTML elements displaying the values.  I can use `em` units to try to not get any digits partially displayed (not 100% effective though, unless forcing a monospaced font, which results in much less visible data in the viewport).  But even using such techniques, I still wind up with values displayed as `58.4848`.

Can CSS be used to solve this task?

Comment: is it about the number of digits or the size of your number that you don't want to be more than a maximum, and in this case remove some of the digits? Because in this case you have the option of using overflow: hidden; and text-overflow: clip;

Comment: @ceyquem Good question.  It's the number of digits.

Comment: you are not gone have a great solution for this with css. Do you have control, how are you getting the data from the backend? It should be formated on arrival.

Comment: @Dejan.S I agree 100%. Unfortunately, I have zero control. I only get the data from their backend through their website, and I completely agree they should be formatting it.  But they don't, and I'm the one that has to interpret their mess.  BTW, if CSS cannot help, I will definitely accept an correct answer that states that CSS *currently* does not have the functionality to help, as long as you explain just a little as to why it will not help.

Comment: In your case I would format the values with javascript in the frontend.

Comment: do you need to round or just cut it?

Comment: @Dejan.S No need to round. Just cutting it is fine. Also, if you have any ideas besides setting a fixed width and hiding the overflow, I'm all ears (well, eyes).

Comment: Seems only JS will work here - example: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/format-currency/

Comment: What is the problem with using a monospaced font for the numbers? It can often be good because it aligns them correctly.

Comment: @AHaworth The only issue is that they occupy more horizontal width.  That said, if you have a way to use them that would generate the desired results specified above, I'm very interested in reading your answer.